# Which is better for tkinter grid, placing individual items or looping through list to place them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a few very large forms that I have been working on in tkinter and Im not sure which way I should implement all the buttons and text boxes. Or if I should just not do it in python/find a new way entirely... The end game is that it is connected to a sqlite3 database and it stores the entries there for me to export later.

First way, I have made each individual input box and placed it where I wanted it, which ended up being 426 lines of code and looked like this over and over again... Much more straight forward on what it's doing than the second option..

```
tk.Label(window,text="Lead Operator: ").grid(row=1,column=0)
Operator2 = tk.StringVar()
operator2_entry = tk.Entry(window,textvariable=Operator2)
operator2_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Second option I tried is a list with all 50 some inputs and looping through different sections of the list to place them where I wanted them to go and looks like this.. I feel like option two is convoluted but it does several inputs at once..

```
for item in list(labels)[10:18:4]:
    tk.Label(master,text=item).grid(row=list(labels.keys()).index(item)+2,column=0)
for item in list(variable)[10:18:4]:
    item = tk.StringVar()
for item in list(entries)[10:18:4]:
    tk.Entry(master,textvariable=list(variable.keys()).index(item[:-6])).grid(row=list(entries.keys()).index(item)+2,column=1)
```

I couldn't tell you which is more efficient but the end program is already over 30MB and takes at least 2-3 seconds to start up without one of the biggest forms I need so I'm not sure if doing option two would help cut down on that or not.
Should I abandon python and go for something in a different language? I am not that great at programming yet so I don't even know what forms like this would usually be coded in.

Comment: If you need to repeat something more than a few times, the best option is always loop through it, i.e. your second approach is better since it adheres to the DRY principle.  however it's still unclear why you need to iterate through 3 different *copies* of lists in the same slices as all you're doing is placing the widgets but not assigning them for reference.  You could have done all three things under `for i in range(2)` and it would achieve the same thing you're doing right now.  It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve at the moment.

Comment: A [MCVE] of what you're trying to attempt would probably help explain the situation.

Comment: @Idlehands The theory behind the three loops was that I would create the label with the first, the second would use the item in the list and turn it into a StringVar() named after the item, then the third would create the entry and link it to the StringVar().. And after the second loop it starts returning StringVar cannot be subscripted. At most I can remove the second loop to get what I wanted.. Whether or not  the second loop works that way, IDK.. I understand DRY but I feel like the second approach is more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the simplest solution is to create a function that takes a label, row, and column, and creates the label and entry for that row and column.

Next, create a data structure that represents the layout of your form. You can either embed the rows and columns, or assume row 1 of the data structure goes in row 1, etc. You can use formatting in your code to make it easy to visualize the form.

Here's a really simple example that assumes all of the input fields are the same size. You don't have to do it this way, but it illustrates the technique:

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_entry(parent, label, row, column):
    label = tk.Label(parent, text=label, justify="right")
    entry = tk.Entry(parent)
    label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="e")
    entry.grid(row=row, column=column+1)

    return entry

layout = (
    ("First Name", 0, 0),  ("Address Line 1", 0, 2),
    ("Last Name",  1, 0),  ("Address Line 2", 1, 2),
                           ("City", 2, 2),
                           ("State", 3, 2),
                           ("Zip", 4, 2),
)

root = tk.Tk()
form = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief="groove")
form.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
form.grid_rowconfigure((0,2), weight=1)

entries = {}
for (label, row, column) in layout:
    entry = create_entry(form, label, row, column)
    entries[label] = entry

root.mainloop()
```

The above code yields a form that looks like this:

[image]

This example doesn't use `StringVar` because that just adds an extra object that needs to be managed, and most of the time you simply don't need it. The example stores each entry in a dictionary, with the key being the label. So, for example, to get the current value of the "City" field you can use `entries['City'].get()`

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Have any advice on fitting the form to screen size with scrollbars? Cause I had trouble finding a way to do that as well while using grid.

Comment: As an update, started messing with this. I like it a lot and it works well. I have had to create a few different functions and layout variables through the process because of how the form is laid out. I.E. some labels take multiple inputs so I had to make a function to have two entries instead of just the one. And also a function for creating just field labels. I hate that I am redoing it, but it looks a lot better and I think after I get it all set up I can just import the same functions into the other forms and go at it. Thanks again!